# Ignore MongoDB socket connection on Spring Test

Tags: spring, mongodb, testing, spring-boot, junit

I am using mongo in my spring project, but I cant connect to mongo server. Anyone knows a way to ignore this bean when executing tests, because sometimes I dont have the mongo server up and I dont want that this build fail.

I really like to know if I can ignore it using SpringRunner.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
public class ApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. 
Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: localhost}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: localhost}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost}}]
```

Spring components:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Dalston.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

PS I stopped the mongodb at localhost intentionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using embedded mongodb.

Dependency (https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I added specific configuration on application-test.yml (execute using spring.profile.active=test)

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: dbtest
      host: localhost
      port: 27028
```

And the ApplicationTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
public class ApplicationTests {

    private static final String LOCALHOST = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "dbtest";
    private static final int MONGO_TEST_PORT = 27028;
    private static MongodProcess mongoProcess;
    private static Mongo mongo;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initializeDB() throws IOException {
        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder()
            .version(Version.Main.V3_3)
            .net(new Net(LOCALHOST, MONGO_TEST_PORT, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .build();

        MongodExecutable mongodExecutable = null;
        try {
            mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
            mongoProcess = mongodExecutable.start();
            mongo = new MongoClient(LOCALHOST, MONGO_TEST_PORT);
            mongo.getDB(DB_NAME);
        } finally {
            if (mongodExecutable != null)
                mongodExecutable.stop();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {}

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutdownDB() throws InterruptedException {
        if (mongo != null) mongo.close();
        if (mongoProcess != null) mongoProcess.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50579963/297907 unable-to-download-embedded-mongodb-behind-proxy-using-automatic-configuration - Not useful this answer in my case

Comment: did you try add proxy config on your maven settings?

Comment: No, How to add proxy config in mvn setting? I am not sure -we may not allow to download zip out side corporate network.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable Spring Boot's auto configuration of MongoDB by adding the following annotation to your `ApplicationTests` class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

This will prevent Spring Boot from creating the MongoClient (assuming there are no *other* classes in your test context annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication`).

Comment: Im going to assume his `Application.class` has `@SpringBootApplication`.

Another option is to use an embedded mongo dependency for tests:
`<dependency>
      <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>`

Comment: I'm triying this approach, using embedded mongo. The answer above answer how to exclude the autoconfiguration, but my problem isnt solved yet.